# SDK for windows phone for Twitter API

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to develop a sample App for Twitter on WindowsPhone7. So anybody suggest me if any SDK for Windows Phone is available. Also any code samples for the OAuth API implementation.
Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to put your email. Just check the answers provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few tutorial about buliding Twitter app. [An example.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx) There are also a lot examples of [Twitter apps in WPF](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=315275) or OpenSource projects like [Witty](http://wittytwitter.codeplex.com/) which can be easly changed to SL for WP7.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side OAuth manager DLL / Documentation:
http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/releases/view/57233

You can view the source here:
http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66350#1710422

Doc here:
http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/OAuthManager1.1

It allows you to specify params like username, password, consumer key, secret key, and it generates the required HTTP headers for you.

See also, [this discussion](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/discussions/254446).