# Is there a Twitter SDK for the Windows Phone Platform?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SDK for windows phone for Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729877/sdk-for-windows-phone-for-twitter-api)

I have been building a Windows Phone Application. There are some Pictures and Comments that I  need to share with my friends to Twitter and Facebook.

But I haven't found any Twitter SDK For Windows Phone Platform.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share only comments(i.e text) you can make use of the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class of Windows phone, which allows you to share to both Twitter and facebook as well.

But if you want to share pictures or if you want to implement a customized twitter sharing functionality, you can make use of some third party libraries like [Hammock](http://nuget.org/packages/Hammock), [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) etc.

And for customized facebook sharing, this [Article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/wFace-windows-phone-7-facebook-integration-part-1.aspx) may help you